# Как уничтожить несколько рядом стоящих объекта?

Tags: unity3d

Я реализую игру bubble shooter, в которой игрок стреляет разноцветными шариками по другим шарикам и если, например, зеленый шарик попадает в 2 или больше рядом стоящих зеленых шарика, то они все втроём уничтожаются. Аналогично для других цветов.

Как мне реализовать следующую вещь: после того, как я выстрелил и попал по шарикам того же цвета, как мне осуществить проверку на то, сколько рядом стоящих шариков того же цвета еще есть там и все уничтожить?

Я вижу только способ OnTriggerEnter(), но так я проверю только первый попавшийся шарик, а как проверить еще рядом стоящие на цвет?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужны только те, которые соприкасаются с вашим шариком триггерами, то вижу такое решение:
1. Когда у шарика срабатывает OnTriggerEnter проверять шарик ли это, если да - вносить его в список соседей, если это пуля - отрабатывать столкновение с пулей.
2. Когда у шарика срабатывает OnTriggerExit - исключать вышедший шарик из списка соседей.
3. При столкновении с пулей вызывать у себя метод уничтожения. Этот метод проходит по списку всех своих соседей, сверяет их цвет со своим и если цвета совпадают вызывает уже у них метод уничтожения. Соседи соответственно, в этом же методе так же обходят список своих соседей.
Чтобы этот сигнал не зацикливался, ввести какой-нибудь bool, который проверять при входе в метод уничтожения - если он false - делать true и начинать обход. В итоге второй раз у одного и того же шарика обход уже не начнётся и вы избежите зацикливания.